Movie or episode with an upstairs murder room
Relatively recent (say since 2000), likely a film but maybe not.   English language, American, not animated.   Here's what I remember:

Woman is at a strangers house.   Might be a hook up with a guy from a bar.  
House is two story.  In a city.  Think it's a corner lot.   Grungy.  Ghetto.  
She is talking to him downstairs.   House is dirty, sparsely decorated.   Old furniture.   She drinks a beer or something.  
Somehow she is unconscious.  She wakes up upstairs where he has a murder room.  
He plays loud music.   Death metal probably.   There's a crude maze, with glass, maybe barbed wire.   Plywood walls set up.  
He wears a mask.  Pretty sure it's a bull/minotaur.   He has a sharp weapon and likely a butchers apron on. 
75% sure she is rescued by a cop.    I believe the cop is female too and finds her way upstairs to shoot him while he's still dressed up.  
Murderer is white.   One of the other two is not if I recall.  Could be hispanic or black, not sure.  

That's all I recall.   I went though my 1250 film history on Netflix and nothing stuck out.   That's why I think it could be an episode of a show.   Hell, maybe even Dexter for all I know. 

This is from episode 7.03 from Dexter: http://dexter.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_703:_Buck_the_System

Ray is a psychotic Serial Killer who murders female victims in a grotesque yet unique ritual while wearing a Bullhorned Helmet.
In Speltzer's house, Garrett is chased through a freakish maze while he stalks her in a bullhorn helmet. Deb hears her screams and breaks in to the house. She confronts Speltzer but he knocks her to the ground, about to kill her until Dexter shows up and knocks him out with a plank.

You can see a scene from the next episode where you can see the maze in Youtube: 




Thank you!   That's the one I was thinking of, though the YouTube clip is from the next episode, not the one with the specific scene.

@dvaeg You are right, I changed the answer to reflect this.
